# Netduino plus, SD Card cannot get basic example working

Tags: c#, netduino

Hi I want to try my SD card on de the netduino plus.
I downloaded the SDK from this website yesterday.

I could not find documentation so I figured out the following code.
However it gives "CLR_E_VOLUME_NOT_FOUND".. What do I do wrong ?
I read something online about mounting and a certain dll (SecretLabs.NETMF.IO.dll ) but I cannot find that dll.

Can anybody help me getting started ?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var fileName = Path.Combine(dir, "test.txt");
        Debug.Print(fileName);
        byte[] testBytes = new byte[] { 1,2,3,4 };
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, testBytes);
    }

}
```

Output :

\test.txt

Exception System.IO.IOException - CLR_E_VOLUME_NOT_FOUND (1)

Message:

System.IO.Path::NormalizePath [IP: 0070]

System.IO.Path::GetFullPath [IP: 001a]

System.IO.FileStream::.ctor [IP: 0009]

System.IO.File::WriteAllBytes [IP: 0012]

NetduinoPlusApplication1.Program::Main [IP: 0025]

A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.IO.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.IO.dll

Comment: If you put it in a PC does it have a FAT file system? If so, must one mount it in .NET Micro somehow? [update] I didn't read that part about mounting it...that's probably it.

Comment: This site seems to have that DLL http://code.google.com/p/netdreamo/source/detail?r=3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been helped at the Netduino Forum, [see this forum post](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/825-sd-card-cannot-get-basic-example-working/).

I needed to write to the `\SD\` folder. `Mounting/dll` was only necessary for the plain Netduino with an additional SD card shield.

Three quick things:

1. The MicroSD card will be mounted at `\SD\` rather than `\`
2. MicroSD cards up to *2GB* are generally supported.
3. `SecretLabs.NETMF.IO` is only needed for manually mounting and dismounting--on the *regular Netduino*. The *Netduino Plus* automatically mounts and dismounts MicroSD Cards.

Comment: I was having issues, "\SD\" helped, thank you! But also I needed to ad a reference to System.IO.dll

Answer (score 1):

Check out the \Samples\SDCardTest in the http://netduinohelpers.codeplex.com/ project for a complete example which is aware of the various Netduino platforms (for instance, the SD card chip select pin for the Netduino Mini is different than the one for the Netduino or the Netduino Plus). As of firmware version 4.1.1 Beta 1, High Capacity microSD cards are supported and have been tested successfully up to 8GB.